# Error when trying to use mexopencv in matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex

I am trying to use mexopencv on my system which has:

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

opencv 2.4.2

gcc-4.4

matlab 2012

and they all are working. I also used some c++ codes to test mex and it worked fine.
I used  [this](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/) to install mexopencv. Also did [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.matlab/bv7FVNJANSI/fAn7Vj2TTwgJ) because of some error I got which mentioned libstdc++.so.6

Now when I try something like:

```
a = cv.imread('pic.jpg');
```

I get:

```
Error using cv.imread
Invalid MEX-file '/home/primepc09/mexopencv/+cv/imread.mexa64': /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4:
undefined symbol: _ZNK9QCheckBox15minimumSizeHintEv
```

Any idea why I get this?

Comment: no it was installed, it said i have 4:4.8. i have tested it with 4.7 and it worked

Comment: For those who might come here: I found out that this symbol has been removed in qt 4.8. I don't know why mexopencv still looks for it but this is probably the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unresolved symbol from QT library. Make sure you have QT installed on your system:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep libqt
```

If you don't have it, you need to install it.

Comment: I have all qt libs installed but still run into this problem. any particular version / package that needs to be installed?